# Time Series forecasting using ARIMA and R

Tags: r, time-series

I am doing a time series forecasting using ARIMA/AUTO ARIMA. My data consists of 1440 Observations, i.e., I have one day data with each observation recorded at 1 minute interval (24*60).

Use to Code given below to generate a sample data-frame

### Sample Dataset

```
sample_date <- seq(as.POSIXct("2018-09-15 00:00:00", tz = "GMT"),
                   as.POSIXct("2018-09-15 23:00:00", tz = "GMT"),
                   by = 60)
inp <- sample(8000:15000, length(sample_date), replace = TRUE)
sdata  <- data.frame(read_date = sample_date, input = inp)
```

This continues until 23:00:00, I have done a bit of my trial and error, would like more inputs to get a better understanding.

### Code

```
a_xts = xts(sdata$input, order.by = sdata$read_date)

s_ts <- ts(a_xts, freq = 24*60)

fit <- auto.arima(s_ts)

forecast(fit, h = 180)
```

As simple as that, I would like to know how to auto-set that start for the time-series data. Also, after forecasting is done, how do I plot the output with actual data continuation.

### Current ARIMA Output

```
Point Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
82861      11013.844 7317.401 14710.29 5360.6215 16667.07
```

### Expected Output

```
 Point                  Forecast    Lo 80    Hi 80     Lo 95    Hi 95
2018-09-15 00:10:00     11013.844 7317.401 14710.29 5360.6215 16667.07
```

1. I would like to know how do you set up the start in ts()
2. I would like to automate the start in ts(), i.e., read the timeframe directly from the data (if possible)
3. I would like to convert the forecast into a dataframe with the 'Point' values replaced by the predicted 'Time Series' date value. (Just like the expected output)

Any inputs and suggestion would really provide value.

Thanks

Comment: Please create a sample dataframe so that a person can look into your data and suggest some solution.

Comment: Hey Vikas, no one can work on your data until you provide it in a structured way. for eg.  val = c(10081, 12023, 13679). something like this so that people can directly use it in their notebooks.

Comment: Hey Girijesh, thanks for responding. Please use the code above to generate a sample dataset.

Comment: I would like to ask one thing after using Arima model what is your intent to forecast. Do you want to predict future values or what?

Comment: I would like to forecast the values for next three hours and load it into a dataframe, the problem I encounter is that the forecast output needs to be converted into a POSIX format.

Comment: what about using predict function. Suppose your Arima model is fit then you can use following method for predicting n values     pred = predict(fit, n.ahead = 1*n)

Comment: did it work for you?